Anyone know of a plugin/method to sort/organize organic objects into "tightest fit" with least amount of negative space between them?
Does anyone know a way to take a collection of organic/randomly shaped objects and sort them (ie. move and rotate) in a way whereby the least amount of negative space is between the objects, within the containing hull of all objects?
For example, laying out rocks where there is minimal space between the shapes:


For 2D objects you could use UV packing. For 3D objects I think it's very hard, a many months long project.

UV Packer or similar could be perfect. Thank you!!
